# Action argument type validation in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, get

I've an Action method accepting a **long** value in my controller:

```
public virtual ActionResult GetInfo(long Id)
```

If someone hijacks the POST/GET request (for example changing **GetInfo?Id=23** to **GetInfo?Id=THIS_IS_A_STRING**), the response contains the stacktrace of the error.

How to avoid this? How can intercept via controller the bad argument and redirect the user to another page?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is do is add a custom error handler to the web.comfig. Something like this:

```
<system.web>
   <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorHandler/Index">
     <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/ErrorHandler/NotFound"/>
   </customErrors>
<system.web/>`
```

This will handle any errors you miss and keep from displaying the system error messages to your users.

Next I would use the MVC controller OnException to customize error responces.

```
public class UserMvcController : Controller
   {
      protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
      {
         filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;

         //Log the error!!
         _Logger.Error(filterContext.Exception);

         //Redirect
         filterContext.Result = RedirectToAction("Index", "ErrorHandler");
         {
            ViewName = "~/Views/ErrorHandler/Index.cshtml"
         };
      }
   }
```

Comment: I’m not sure such behavior corresponds to a 404?